# Bug with multiple connections to Interbase with php 7

Tags: php, php-7.1, interbase, php-7.2, php-7.0

It seems PHP 7 changed a bit the way to work with the Interbase module.

Same code on PHP 5.6 works flawlessly.

If you have one open link to an Interbase/Firebird database and you open **another** one to the same database the first link it's closed.

One example of code can be:

```
$conx = ibase_pconnect(DB_HOST . ":" . DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PWD,DB_CHARACTER) or die(ibase_errcode() . ' ' . ibase_errmsg()); 

$conx2 = ibase_pconnect(DB_HOST . ":" . DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PWD,DB_CHARACTER) or die(ibase_errcode() . ' ' . ibase_errmsg()); 

$sql = 'SELECT something from somewhere';

$query = ibase_query($conx, $sql);

while ($row = ibase_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $row['something'];
}
```

DB_xxx are defined variables with the users, password, ..... of the database.

The result it's the same if instead of **ibase_pconnect** we write **ibase_connect**

If you run that code you won't get nothing, and on the page log you will see something like:

```
supplied resource is not a valid Firebird/InterBase link resource in ....

ibase_fetch_assoc(): Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -504 Invalid cursor reference Cursor is not open ....
```

If we remove the line with the $conx2 all will work perfectly.

On my php.ini I have this (exactly the same than on PHP 5.6):

```
ibase.allow_persistent = 1

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
ibase.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
ibase.max_links = -1
```

Interbase module for php7 has a new option which it's generating this problem ?

Comment: It may well be that this is a bug in the PHP 7 port of ext/interbase. There are very few people who use this extension, so not exactly well tested. Can you log a bug on bugs.php.net?

Comment: In particular, I don't think this line is correct: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_MASTER/ext/interbase/interbase.c#943 This zend_list_close should probably be a zend_list_delete, otherwise it will simply always destroy the resource.

Comment: Hi NIkiC, i'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS which uses PHP 7.0.4. On bugs.php.net says if I'm not using the last version (7.0.7 I should upgrade before posting a bug). I sent a bug to Ubuntu bugtracker the same day I posted here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php7.0/+bug/1578600

Comment: Hi NikiC, looking at the source and your profile it seems the bug it's currently on the last php version, so I created the bug on the php bugtracker as you said. Thx. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72175

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a php-7.0 bug.

If was fixed some time ago on version 7.2.16 and was fixed too in lower versions.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72175